# alter XML/JSON variant object

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In our Snowflake datalake, we have a requirement to delete corresponding PII data (e.g. email address) from all tables when a customer requests a forget me.
In the COMPOSED and MODELLED Layer where the attributes are stored in individual columns this is easy, however I am struggling to work out how to do this in the RAW layer, where native XML / JSON datasets are retained. How would I amend these native XML/JSON variant dataobjects and remove the PII elements, such as email address.

Comment: Have you looked into using Dynamic Data Masking in Snowflake instead of deleting the data?  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-column-ddm.html

Comment: Unfortunately Dynamic Data Masking does not comply with Privacy regulatory requirements around "forget me requests"  - where the data needs to be physically deleted from all systems :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update a VARIANT column using OBJECT_INSERT like this:

```
UPDATE <tablename> SET properties = OBJECT_INSERT(properties, key, 'new_value', TRUE) WHERE properties:key::VARCHAR = 'existing_value';
```

The **TRUE** above is the  if you want to overwrite data, see more [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_insert.html)

Cast to **VARCHAR** is optional but good to have explicit cast rather than rely on implicit casting.

Comment: Thank you Sergiu, did not know about this option - it appears very promising. I will try this solution.